# rstudio document outline not indenting sub routines

Tags: r, rstudio, comments

I would like to use the document outline feature in RStudio to more effectively allow my code reviewer to navigate a file, but my outline is not indenting like I would expect it to. I'm wondering if it's possible to get the output I want. Reproducible example below:

```
my_function <- function(x,y){
  # Unconditional ====
  print("Set some variables for the function")
  # Condition 1 ====
  if(x>100){
    # Action 1 ====  
    print("Do some stuff to x")
    # Action 2 ====  
    z <- x*pi
    }
  # Condition 2 ====
  else if(y<=100){
    # Action 1 ====  
    print("Do some stuff to x")
    # Action 2 ====  
    z <- psigamma(y)
    }
  # Condition 3 ====
  else if(x<=100){
    # Action 1 ====  
    print("Do some stuff to x")
    # Action 2 ====
    z <- x+100
  }
  # Otherwise ====
  else{
    z <- x+y
  }
  return(z)
}
```

The example creates this outline:
[image]

I would like the outline to look like this:

my_function
- Unconditional
- Condition 1
-- Action 1
-- Action 2
- Condition 2
-- Action 1
-- Action 2
- Condition 3
-- Action 1
-- Action 2
- Otherwise

Comment: If you have a feature request for Rstudio, then you should probably post it to their support forum instead: https://community.rstudio.com/. Plus "if" statements really aren't sub routines; they don't create scopes

Comment: @MrFlick I'm posting the question there as well, but I'm just trying to clarify if it is possible to structure the outline myself using a modified syntax or structuring the code differently.

Comment: @MarkDruffel is there a solution to your request? I would also like to have such an the outline.

Comment: @pbraeutigm I opened a feature request - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6441.  I see it was marked as stale, don't think I got many upvotes...